# Which one works faster?

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, return

Do these 2 have any differences?

```
if (condition)
{
    std::cout << "Condition is true";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Condition is false";
}
```

OR

```
if (condition)
{
    std::cout << "Condition is true";
    return 0;
}
std::cout << "Condition is false";
```

I know that is not good to use the second one because maybe you have some more code after it.
But at the end of the code that we don't have anything after that else, isn't it better to use the second one?

Comment: Cannot be answered, just check the generated assembly and measure. Spoiler: It does not make a difference, assembly will likely be (almost) identical, just let the compiler do its job, do yours  - make the code correct and readable.

Comment: Note, that cost of an if is completely negligible compared to the cost of writing text out.

Comment: Anyway both code fragments are not equivalent, there is no `return 0;` in the first one.

Comment: You should not even wonder for performance here... Your job as a programmer is to write correct and readable code for future mainteners. Low level optimization is the job of the compiler. Only if performances do no meet requirements, and if profiling proved that a specific part of code needs low level optimization you should use those low level optimization tricks, but you should be aware that what is optimum for a compiler and a set of options may not be optimum for different options or a different compiler...

Comment: A company I worked for many years ago insisted that every function had a single return statement. This company relied heavily on COM so every COM call was wrapped in a conditional resulting very deeply nested if-statements. One needed 500 character page widths to read it. It was, IMHO, a laudable goal but a couple of return statements would really have helped. My point here that when anybody tells you that in all circumstances you must write code in a certain way one can almost always find a contradictory use case. My motto is, suck it and see.

Comment: @systemcpro: Yes that approach did help debugging as you could put a break on that single `return`. But it was flawed, e.g. lambdas and `throw`, and even the occasional exit.

Comment: @Bathsheba "There is no silver bullet" - Bjarne Stroustrop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified the original question a bit as follows,

```
void f1() {
    int a = 0;
    if (a > 0) {
        a = 1;
    } else {
        a = 2;
    }
}

void f2() {
    int a = 0;
    if (a > 0) {
        a = 1;
        return;
    } 
    a = 2;
}
```

Here are the compiled assembly. `f1()` and `f2()` are nearly identical.

```
f1():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        jle     .L2
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jmp     .L4
.L2:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2
.L4:
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
f2():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        jle     .L6
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jmp     .L5
.L6:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2
.L5:
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

The only difference is that `.L4` has a `nop`. More details can be found [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/snf49Y673).

Comment: thats the compiled assembly without compiler optimizations. Without optimizations turned on the assembly can have arbitrarily poor performance

Comment: Agreed. My point is they don't make much difference even at assembly level before complier optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Write code to express intent and to be readable.

Consider that this does make a difference:

```
if (condition)
{
    std::cout << "Condition is true";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Condition is false";
}
do_something_in_any_case();
```

vs

```
if (condition)
{
    std::cout << "Condition is true";
    return 0;
}
std::cout << "Condition is false";
do_something_in_any_case();
```

Further, consider that code is not written once and then stays like that forever. Code is refactored often. What is the meaning of `condition`? Does it mean that you definitely need to `return 0;` ? Or did you only place the `return 0;` there because in your code there is no `do_something_in_any_case()` ? If it is the latter then the first version is better at expressing the intend. If at some later point you have to add some `do_something_in_any_case()` you will have to remove the `return 0;` again, because it wasn't in the right place from the start.

I tried to argue in favour of the first, though one can find similar arguments in favor of the second. The point is just that thats the kind of considerations you have to make when deciding between the first and the second: Which one is better at expressing the intend. Which one is more likely to be fine with future refactorings. Which one is more readable. ...

So much for style and clean code, which is largely opinion based and depends very much on what `condition` really is. Concerning performance, there is no other way than to measure. However, you should write clear, correct and readable code first. Because wrong and hard to read code is worse than code that takes a microsecond too mucht time. If you care about performance turn on compiler optimizations and only manually rearrange the code when you know that compiler optimizations are not sufficient to meet the required performance.

As the two have equivalent observable behavior, no difference in performance is to be expected. The compiler will notice that the two are effectively doing exactly the same and will rearrange the code to be performant.